# SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016 insert into Varible Table Performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I'm testing a new SQL Server 2016 Standard, restored from a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise.

I have a stored procedure that used to execute in 1:40, now it is taking 36 min. It had a rather large insert into a @variable table I simply changed it to a #Temporary table and back down to 1:40.

Is there an issue with SQL Server 2016 and @Variable tables

( although I use #temp tables for anything with some size to it, my predecessor used variable tables for everything... 100's of Stored procedures... )

Comment: The new cardinality estimator estimates 100 for table variables as opposed to 1 in 2012 -- this is an improvement in most use cases, and also looks at some statistics differently. If you switch the compatibility level down to 110 does it work as it did previously?

Comment: Thank you for the Quick response, I changed it to 110, it was on SQL 2008(100), it did not help the issue, I stopped the procedure at 5 min